# Armazenar informação por usuário logado sem utilizar Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Gostaria de saber como posso armazenar informações do usuário individualmente sem utilizar Constants e Session para ser acessado pelo meu projeto de acesso a dados?

Utilizava-se constants mas a aplicação foi transformada em SaaS e as constants acabavam dando conflito se houvesse mais de um usuário logado ao mesmo tempo.

O objetivo é armazenar uma connection string dinâmica por usuário para ser usado pela camada de acesso a dados.

Comment: se não vai usar session precisa usar um base da dados, e por um exemplo um token que vai servir de id da sessão do usuário

Comment: Mas eu preciso de acessar essa connection string pra saber em qual banco conectar, não da pra usar uma base de dados

Comment: ao menos precisa de um banco "generico" para guardar as sessões, depois pode usar isso pra decidir o que fazer, como abrir uma conexão específica. Está um pouco confuso, sem mais detalhes fica difícil ajudar, o fato é: para manter uma sessão de usuário logado vai precisar salvar isso num lugar, e poderia ser uma "base de dados de sessões"

Comment: Entendi, e não haveria nenhuma outra maneira de fazer isso?

Comment: Existem diversas abordagens, mas para podermos dar uma resposta é necessário que você apresente um [MCVE]

Answer (score 1):

Realmente, se estiver pensando na segurança dos usuários, ter um banco de dado e um gerenciador de tokens seria uma boa prática.

Mas, cara, se seu foco não for a segurança, e visando resolver teu problema, uma solução (que não é boa, mas funciona) é voce armazenar os usuários que estão logados no localSotorage e usar um socket para atualizar cada storage de usuários quando algum logar, ou algum deslogar.

Alguns pontos que valem destaque:

- se tua aplicação for ter muitos usuários, essa solução se tornará inviável;
- uma forma de colocar um pouco de segurança nisso seria encriptar os dados de alguma forma (com chave fornecida pelo server), sugiro usar o bcrypt;